# Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this error in console on XCode while running simulation of my app. It has a Firstore connection which seems to be working fine. What is this error and how can I eliminate it?

"2023-06-03 15:04:38.483914-0500 Map_events[29237:559658] [connection] nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal_block_invoke [C9] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection"

I tried to find other answers, but I couldn't find the same error

Comment: I have the same problem on a macOS Ventura, Intel platform, Flutter 3.10.6 app development (latest firebase dependencies) with VS Code 1.81.0, XCode 14.3.1, on an iPhone 8 with iOS 16.4.1. It started about 1 or 2 days ago. I get further errors: nw_read_request_report [C48] Receive failed with error "Operation timed out". Are we sure this error is linked to Firebase?

Comment: More errors: nw_endpoint_flow_fillout_data_transfer_snapshot copy_info() returned NULL, and nw_path_necp_check_for_updates Failed to copy updated result (22)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xcode 15 Beta? My guess is that this is an error message only for 15 Beta because Firebase has not yet updated the iOS library to match it accordingly. I imagine Firebase will take care of this sometime soon.

Comment: I get the very same messages about 10'000 times in my log (using Simulator). However, I am using XCode 14.3.1. Any idea what this could be ?  I use Firebase 10.12.0 installed via Package Manager.